# How to delete elements in JSON if key is not a number?

Tags: python, json, pandas, twitter

So I have a large JSON file of 600.000 tweets.
Of these tweets I need to know the exact location.
I do this by running the following code, where I am tring to load the first 40000 tweets. The tweets_data is the loaded JSON file.

```
test_tweets = tweets_data[:40000]

import pandas as pd

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['text'] =    list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], test_tweets))
tweets['lang'] =    list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], test_tweets))
tweets['country'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, test_tweets))
tweets['coordinates'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'], test_tweets))
```

I get an error in the last line, stating that:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-87ebee84f083> in <module>
      9 tweets['lang'] =    list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], test_tweets))
     10 tweets['country'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, test_tweets))
---> 11 tweets['coordinates'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'], test_tweets))
     12 
     13 

<ipython-input-12-87ebee84f083> in <lambda>(tweet)
      9 tweets['lang'] =    list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], test_tweets))
     10 tweets['country'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, test_tweets))
---> 11 tweets['coordinates'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'], test_tweets))
     12 
     13 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I **think** that this is because some of the coordinates data is missing, but I am not sure. I don't mind deleting a few lines, but I am not sure how to.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a few sample tweets? It would be ideal to just create the DataFrame with its constructor but I need to know the format of the tweets to help you

Answer (score 0):

Just as in the previous line, you have to check if `tweet['place']` is not `None` before trying to access `tweet['place'][anything]`

```
tweets['coordinates'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'] if tweet['place'] is not None else None, test_tweets))
```

I'm assuming that there's no need to also check `tweet['place']['bounding_box']`. If that's not a safe assumption, add an additional check.

```
tweets['coordinates'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'] if tweet['place'] and tweet['place']['bounding_box'] else None, test_tweets))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! To be honest I have no idea if 'place' and 'bounding box' are okay as they are. How can I check them as well?

Comment: Check the code that creates the JSON in the first place, to see if it always fills them in.

Comment: Because it comes from a Twitter API, I have no idea to know for sure. Is there a way to check for place and bounding_box as well in the same way I am checking for coordinates?

Comment: Then it should be in the API documentation.

Comment: `if tweet['place'] is not null and tweet['place']['bounding_box'] is not null then ... else ...`